# Cannot compile unreal engine 4.25 with visual studio 2019.7.2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I get this error below when I try to compile unreal engine version four point twenty five (4.25) with visual studio version twenty nineteen point seven point two. (vs2019.7.2) or (16.7.2).

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.2

Does anyone know how to compile this?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HVS, Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------
1>Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (C:\repos).
1>Invalidating makefile for HVSEditor (VisualStudioDTE.Build.cs modified)
1>Building HVSEditor and ShaderCompileWorker...
1>Using Visual Studio 2019 14.27.29111 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
1>Building 5 actions with 12 processes...
1>  [1/5] dte80a.tlh
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(46,5): error MSB3073: The command "C:\WINDOWS\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(46,5): error MSB3073:  C:\repos\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="HVSEditor Win64 Development -Project=\"C:\Users\decil\Desktop\HVS_Game\HVS.uproject\"" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.
1>Done building project "HVS.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 41):

Try delete directory "Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\VisualStudioDTE" and rebuild.

Comment: Such an obscure problem but this worked for me. In 2022 with UE5.0 I followed the same instructions only instead of UE4Editor it was UnrealEditor.

Not sure entirely what triggers this issue but it happened to me for the first time ever after I needed to rebuild development editor.

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU, YOU BEAUTIFUL PERSON YOU