# Unreal engine 4.26.2 source version errors when running

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to set up UE4.26.2 source version but haven't been successful. I have cloned the repo from github, ran Setup and GenerateProjectFiles without errors, set development editor and x64 in Visual studio 2019 and built it without errors but when I try to run the UE I always get the same two errors:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: UE4, Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------
1>Building UE4Editor and ShaderCompileWorker...
1>Using Visual Studio 2019 14.34.31937 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933) and Windows 10.0.20348.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
1>Building 2 actions with 16 processes...
1>  [1/2] UE4Editor.exe
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\UE4.26.2\UnrealEngine-4.26.2-release\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor.exe'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(45,5): error MSB3073: The command "..\..\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UE4Editor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.
1>Done building project "UE4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

LNK1104 cannot open file 'D:\UE4.26.2\UnrealEngine-4.26.2-release\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor.exe'

MSB3073 The command "....\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UE4Editor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.

I have tried various different combinations of VS components, I have installed .net Desktop dev, desktop dev with c++ and game dev with c++. I am using .NET Framework 4.8 SDK with all the previous 4.x targeting packs. I have tried deleting certain content from the Win64 folder and other files which I can't recall, but after I run the UE4 it always builds them again so the errors persist.

Comment: I found [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977059/17200348) on an issue describing the same error as you. Could you try to apply this?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. My avast antivirus put the "UE4Editor.exe" into quarantine, then I restored it and compiled and voila, it works